# How to pass values into php to get table as output?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSliderChanged (slider) {
        var sliderValue = document.getElementById (slider.id + "Value");
        sliderValue.innerHTML = slider.value;
    }

    function Init () {
        var slider = document.getElementById ("slider1");
        OnSliderChanged (slider);
        var slider = document.getElementById ("slider2");
        OnSliderChanged (slider);
    }
</script>
0<input type="range" id="slider1" min="0" max="100" step="1" style=width:50% onchange="OnSliderChanged (this)" />100
<span id="slider1Value" class="sliderValue"></span>
<br /><br /><br />
0<input type="range" id="slider2" min="0" max="100" step="1" style=width:50% onchange="OnSliderChanged (this)" />100
<span id="slider2Value" class="sliderValue"></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'pointer\';" OnMouseOut="this.style.cursor=\'default\';">


<?php
if (isset($_GET['value=20'&&'value1=40']))
{
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$hostname = 'localhost';
$dataname = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Connection failed: ");
$selected = mysql_select_db('testdb',$dataname) or die("Could not select table1");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1`");
$last = '';
echo "<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo"<tr>
         <td>".$row['0']."</th>
         <td>".$row['1']."</td>
  </tr>"; 
  }
 mysql_close($dataname);
 }
else
{
echo " No Values Found";
}
 ?>
```

I am trying to get the input values into the php which should show the table.But am not getting the table as result am getting "No values Found" in the initial page itself. Am new to this php n javascript.. For eg i need to get the table when values 20 n 40 entered as input...Can someone please help me..?

Comment: `isset($_GET['value=20'&&'value1=40'])`?

Comment: Corrected that one as "if ((isset($_POST['value']) && ($_POST['value'] == '20')) && (isset($_POST['value1']) && ($_POST['value1'] == '40')))" Still am not getting..

Comment: Give the input a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `name` attribute in html form in order to access them in server side..

```
0<input type="range" name="value" id="slider1" min="0" max="100" step="1" style=width:50% onchange="OnSliderChanged (this)" />100
<span id="slider1Value" class="sliderValue"></span>
<br /><br /><br />
0<input type="range" name="value1" id="slider2" min="0" max="100" step="1" style=width:50% onchange="OnSliderChanged (this)" />100
<span id="slider2Value" class="sliderValue"></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'pointer\';" OnMouseOut="this.style.cursor=\'default\';">
```

Also make the form **method** to **post** with `method="post"`

Comment: <form action="<?php echo $_POST['$datamodel.php']; ?>"     method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="value" id="slider1"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="value1" id="slider2"  /> is this Coorect?

Comment: `value` should be `20` and `value1` should be `40`. So set the `value` attributes properly in your form..

Comment: `<form action="<?php echo $_POST['$datamodel.php']; ?>" method="POST"> <input type="hidden" name="value" value="20" id="slider1" /> <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="40" id="slider2" /><input type="submit"></form>`

Comment: Seems this is a defined value. But i need to get different tables for multiple combinations. Eg.Input selected as 20 n 40 table1 will be displayed, for input 30 n 60 need to display table2. Goes on..

Comment: Then why are you validating if the input is `20` and `40` from the server side? You have to validate only if the inputs are set.. `if (isset($_POST['value']) &&  isset($_POST['value1']))`